# How to use Javascript to open a link (external website) without HTTPS protocol?

Tags: javascript

This code (with HTTPS protocol), successfully opens `https://www.google.com`.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v7bg69L/2/)**

```
<script>
    function openInNewTab() {
        var url = 'https://www.google.com';
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    }
</script>

<div onclick="openInNewTab();">OPEN LINK ON A NEW WINDOW</div>
```

But when I use this code (without HTTP protocol), it opens `https://www.example.com/www.google.com` instead.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v7bg69L/3/)**

```
<script>
    function openInNewTab() {
        var url = 'www.google.com';
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    }
</script>

<div onclick="openInNewTab();">OPEN LINK ON A NEW WINDOW</div>
```

Is there a way to use Javascript to open an external website without HTTPS protocol?

Comment: you need to have a protocol when fetching cross domain ... at least `//www.google.com` - then the protocol will depend on the protocol of the page making the request (http or https)

Comment: Yes, otherwise the browser will assume that it is a relative path of the current domain.

Comment: Can you tell us why you do not want to use "HTTP protocol"?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use an external anchor tag with the target set to _blank?

E.g

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">OPEN LINK A NEW WINDOWS</a>`

Although in this example, google will redirect to https because security

Answer (score 2):

A URL string without a protocol at the beginning (or the "protocol-relative shorthand" `//` for which [there are good arguments to not use it](https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url)) will be considered either an **anchor URL** if it begins with a hash, `#fragment`, or otherwise a **relative URL**. A relative URL just puts `www.google.com` on top of the current level of the path. If your location is `http://www.example.com` then that becomes `http://www.example.com/www.google.com`. Or if it's `http://foo.net/bar/baz/quux.html`, that becomes `http://foo.net/bar/baz/www.google.com`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = new URL('http://example.com');
```

Keep in mind that when you are opening http://google.com they have a redirect to their https protocol. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Further notes which won't answer the question should be put into the comment section!